# Upload a file via an ajax POST request with a Silex-based PHP app on the backend

Tags: php, file-upload, silex

**Disclaimer:** I know very little about PHP; I have only recently started to play with it.

**Background:** I want to upload a file using javascript on the client-side and PHP on the backend. On the backend, I am experimenting with the Silex PHP microframework.

**Client code:**

**html**

```
<form id="fileform">
  <input id="filefield" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
var form = document.querySelector('#fileform');
var fileField = document.querySelector('#filefield');
form.addEventListener('submit', formSubmit, false);


function formSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let formData = new FormData();
  let file = fileField.files[0];
  formData.append('uploadedFile', file);

  let config = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'default',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': false
    },
    body: formData
  };

  fetch('http://localhost:8000/uploads/test', config).then((response) => {
    console.log('submitted!');
  });
}
```

**Backend code:**

**php (controller in a Silex-based app)**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$uploads->post('/test', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

  $file = $request->files->get('uploadedFile');
  if ($file == NULL) {
    return 'null';
  } else {
    return 'not null';
  }
});
```

**Problem:** I expect to have a file with the name 'uploadedFile' in the `$request->files` object, but either there is nothing in there, or I don’t know how to reach the uploaded file, because the controller believes that `$file == NULL` is true.

As a sanity check, I returned `$request->getContent()` from the controller and inspected the result in the browser. Here is what the backend is getting:

[image]

So it does seem like the backend is getting the contents of the form, with the name `'uploadedFile'`. So what am I doing wrong on the backend? How can I reach this uploaded file in the Silex controller?

It’s all so terribly confusing. Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out it was not a PHP question, but a JavaScript question, after all :-) The error was caused by the incorrect headers in the config object that I was passing to `fetch`:

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': false
},
```

When I omit this part, request headers are:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:363123
content-type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzUZXCxORC35rae15
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:null
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.59 Safari/537.36
```

but if I include it, I screw up the content-type header, which literally becomes:

```
content-type:false
```

So yeah, that was my mistake. Weird, because I distinctly remember that I saw the recommendation to set the content-type header to false when preparing an ajax request somewhere.